# JS Text Loop with Previous, Pause & Next Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I have the below code with me for Text with Next & Previous Button. I want this to loop repeatedly on page load and one button for pause in between the both. All three buttons to be totally on the right side on the same line of displaying the text. Please support me.. thanks...

```
<!DOC HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var messages = [
    'Messages for <em>kindergarden</em> class',
    'Message for <em>1st grade</em>',
    'Message for <em>2nd grade</em>',
    'Message for <em>3rd grade</em>',
    'Message for <em>4th grade</em>',
    'Message for <em>5th grade</em>',
    'Message for <em>6th grade</em>'
];

var msgPtr = 0;
function nextMsg(direction) {
  msgPtr = msgPtr + direction;
  if (msgPtr < 0) { msgPtr = messages.length-1; }
  if (msgPtr > messages.length-1) { msgPtr = 0; }
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = messages[msgPtr];
}
window.onload = function () {
  nextMsg(0);
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
em { color:orange; }
#msg { 
font-family:monospace; 
background-color:yellow;
font-size:1em;  
width:890px; 
border:1px dotted red; 
overflow:hidden;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="msg"></div><br>
<button onclick="nextMsg(-1)">&lt;</button>
<button onclick="nextMsg(-1)">||</button>
<button onclick="nextMsg(1)">&gt;</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to call nextMsg() recursively like

```
function nextMsg(direction){
    //snip
    nextMsg(direction);
}
```

I wrote a very quick proof of concept with jQuery that should be rewritten in a cleaner way:
http://jsfiddle.net/5NUPn/5/

Now for displaying both your message and buttons on the same line you need to use float.

```
#msg { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'setInterval(code,millisec)' function. So your code should look like something like this:

```
var msgPtr =0;
var set_interval_id;

function pause() {
    clearInterval(set_interval_id)
}

function play() {
    set_interval_id = setInterval(function() {
        nextMsg(msgPtr);
        msgPtr++;
    }, 2000 /* how often to execute the code (2 sec) */);
}

window.onload = function () {
  play();
}

...

<button onclick="nextMsg(-1)">&lt;</button>
<button onclick="pause()">||</button>
<button onclick="nextMsg(1)">&gt;</button>

....
```